# Python how to parse a list[dict] in python and convert values from nested dictionaries as keys

Tags: python

Need help in writing clean code , I have a yaml parsed output which looks like this :

```
yaml_output = [{'name' : 'alex', 'subjects' : {'maths' : ['grade_1', 'grade_2']}},
               {'name' : 'rio', 'subjects' : {'maths' : ['grade_3', 'grade_2'], 'science : ['grade_4', 'grade_6']}}]
```

I want it create a list of dictionaries with subjects as key and name of the students as value in a dictionary where grades are the keys.

```
desired_output = [{'maths' : {'grade_1' : ['alex'], 'grade_2' : ['alex', 'rio'], 'grade_3' : ['rio']}}, {'science' : {'grade_4' : ['rio'], 'grade_6' : ['rio']}
```

needs subjects as key and name of the students as value in a dictionary where grades are the keys.

```
new_dict = []
for dict in yaml_output:
  for k,v in dict:
    for i,j in dict['subjects']:
      if any(i in dict_list for dict_list in new_dict):
        dict_list[i].append(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Your `for k,v` loop is looking at the wrong data.  You don't want to look at ALL the keys, you want to unravel the subjects key and reference the "name" specifically.

```
yaml_output = [{'name' : 'alex', 'subjects' : {'maths' : ['grade_1', 'grade_2']}},
               {'name' : 'rio', 'subjects' : {'maths' : ['grade_3', 'grade_2'], 'science': ['grade_4', 'grade_6']}}]

out = dict()
for data in yaml_output:
    for k,v in data['subjects'].items():
        if k not in out:
            out[k] = {}
        for g in v:
            if g not in out[k]:
                out[k][g] = []
            out[k][g].append( data['name'] )
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'maths': {'grade_1': ['alex'], 'grade_2': ['alex', 'rio'], 'grade_3': ['rio']}, 'science': {'grade_4': ['rio'], 'grade_6': ['rio']}}
```